# Data as a service using pivotal HAWQ

Tags: json, rest, hadoop, hive, hawq

We have a requirement,where we need to provide data of HAWQ as a restful API to many consumers such as mobile app, web app etc in JSON format with web service security ;basically Data as a service to different applications from data lake.
Can you please help us with detail architecture or some pointers on the same. We are using Pivotal HD 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I would say you could use any application to develop your webservices (ie: spring) and connect to HAWQ via the JDBC driver to query the data and then reformat it to JSON within your webservice.

Comment: Thanks, for the help Parham.